# How to select the file from local drive and save it in another place in the system using xcode,iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, file

My requirement is to select a file from the local drive and save it in the another place in the same machine using xcode.

Comment: use Finder. Xcode is not a file manager. SCNR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the "project navigator", select "Add files to...", choose file from local drive mark checkbox copy files into... press Add button.

Comment: Thanks for replying but in my application in ios i want to pull a file from i phone and i want to save it in an other folder in i phone.Please help me out of this?